# Too much time elapsing between Application_PostMapRequestHandler and Application_AcquireRequestState

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

I'm seeing some weird behavior out of IIS/ASP.NET: there's suddenly a lot of time being taken up somewhere between the Application_PostMapRequestHandler and the Application_AcquireRequestState event (often on the order of 3-4 seconds, but I've seen up to 100 seconds). Does anyone know what work gets done between these two events?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too. It seems to be very rare because I can find very few result about this from google or here. The only maybe useful info I found is:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1147300.aspx

Hope this can help you:)